# Store output as a variable

Tags: bash, batch-file

I'm working on a batch file and I want to know the best way to save output using a `.bat` file, (I'm using Unix too).

What I have done was send the output to a new `.txt` file, save it into a variable then delete the file, but I want to simplify this mechanism. I want to save the output directly, *just to have a better mechanism*.

```
call "...\bin\server.bat"  start ifa
call "...\bin\jar.exe" -cvfM "justateste.zip" "%1"
call "...\curl.exe" -X POST -i -T "justatest.zip" "http://localhost:9080/rest/ifa/v1/triaged-assessments" | tail --lines=2
```

Output, *(it's a random string output)*:

```
d076dc06-b34f-4f1b-bca3-e1c57efdb84c
```

Just need to know the best way to save the result of the `tail --lines=2`.

Full output, *(without tail)*:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 18 Feb 2019 11:34:57 GMT

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 18 Feb 2019 11:34:57 GMT
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.1
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Fri, 18 Feb 2019 11:34:57 GMT
Content-Length: 36

df8f48d8-29f6-4de2-8186-8450c35658c3
.
```

Comment: can you show what the full output is when you run the command, without the tail portion.

Comment: @Gerhard Barnard check the main post, i edited with the full output (it's just a output header and i only need the random string). Thanks.

Comment: So you're asking for the last two lines but not wanting the last line, is that correct? You previously said that your output was `Output: d076dc06-b34f-4f1b-bca3-e1c57efdb84c (it's a random string output)`, but your edit shows that the output would also include a line consisting of just a period **`.`**

Comment: probably need a for loop `for /f "skip=10 delims=" %%i in ('command..') do echo %%i`

Comment: @Compo, yes, it's correct.

Comment: @BetsUnited, what's wrong with using `tail -n 2 | head -n 1` then to isolate only the line you need?

Comment: What's wrong with leaving out the `-i` option from curl (which tells curl to output the HTTP headers) and thus no need for the tail command?

Comment: So taking the previous two comments, would you not be better advised using `"D:\Software\curl_7_53_1_openssl_nghttp2_x64\curl.exe" -X POST -T "justatest.zip" "http://localhost:9080/rest/ifa/v1/triaged-assessments" | head -n 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to catch a command's output in batch is a `for /f` loop.
There is no need for `tail`, when you filter the output (find the line that contains three dashes):

```
@echo off 
set command="...\curl.exe" -X POST -i -T "justatest.zip" "http://localhost:9080/rest/ifa/v1/triaged-assessments"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('%command% ^|findstr ".*-.*-.*-.*"') do set "output=%%a"
echo %output%
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Stephan. I was trying to make this work with your piece of code but always i'm getting a "The system cannot find the path specified." Error.

Comment: then it can't find either `curl.exe` or `justatest.zip`. check your paths.

Comment: Without the for condition (only the set command) the program doesn't return any error but when i put the For condition inside it, returns an error: D:\ScanTeste>for /F "tokens=*" %a in ('"D:\Software\curl_7_53_1_openssl_nghttp2_x64\curl.exe" -X POST -i -T "justatest.zip" "http://localhost:9080/rest/ifa/v1/triaged-assessments" |findstr ".*-.*-.*-.*"') do set "output=%a"
The system cannot find the path specified.

Thanks for the help, @Stephan. I really appreciate it.

Comment: i'm trying to figure out how i can do this, now it's giving me another error type: //the header stuff with the randomstring | was unexpected at this time.
ECHO is off.

Comment: did you forget to escape the pipe (`^|`)?

Comment: Hello @stephan, finally i'm going nice on this but a new problem came out. The for condition is great but it's giving me this error: NDSTR: Line 37 is too long.
FINDSTR: Line 37 is too long. It's possible to replace FINDSTR for something else? Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Ok, i'm using GREP instead of FINDSTR and it's working fine! Thanks for the help! :D